# Типовая структура web-проекта (сайта)

Tags: структуры, веб-программирование, frontend, gulp

Здравствуйте.

Не подскажите, какая структура должна быть у проекта, согласно всем стандартам?

Например, раньше при front-end разработке у меня было:

```
|--/style..   
|--/js..    
|--/img..   
|--*.html
```

Вроде, все понятно! Сегодня начал изучать сборщики, пробую Gulp:

Создаю таски, смотрю туториалы... везде какое-то странное дерево проекта: папки app, assets, public...  Я примерно понимаю, что делят на файлы разработки и на файлы (папку) релиза, подобно веткам в GIT'е.

Но все равно хочется услышать мнение, основанное на вашем опыте, и увидеть типовую структуру проекта с использованием, например, gulp (stylus, autoprefix, minify...).

Что и куда складывать, что и куда компилировать?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
|-/builder
|--/node_modules
|--Gulpfile.js
|-/src
|--/assets
|---/styles
|---/images
|----/design
|----/content
|---/scripts
|----/local
|----/vendor
|--/templates
|---/pages
|---/blocks
|-/built
|--/js
|--/css
|--/img
|--*.html
```

**Обновление**

Built - папка продакшена.
Src - папка исходников.
Builder - папка для тасков.

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего app - серверная часть приложения, public - клиентская. В последний могут быть папки для разработки и продакшена. Соответственно, все сжатые и объединенные стили и скрипты должны лежать в папке продакшена.